# Updating a data frame's columns based on other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame containing a person's stage, as follows (this is only a sample of a very large one):

```
df = structure(list(DeceasedDate = c(0.283219178082192, 1.12678843226788, 
2.02865296803653, 0.892465753424658, NA, 0.88013698630137, NA
), LastClinicalEventMonthEnd = c(0.244862981988838, 1.03637744165398, 
10.9464611555048, 0.763698598427194, 3.35011412354135, 0.677397228564181, 
3.83687211440893), FirstYStage = c("N/A", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "3.1"), SecondYStage = c("N/A", "N/A", "2", "N/A", "2", 
"N/A", "3.1"), ThirdYStage = c("N/A", "N/A", "2", "N/A", "2", 
"N/A", "3.1"), FourthYStage = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "2", 
"N/A", "3.1"), FifthYStage = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
"N/A", "N/A")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

The 5 right hand columns are a stage of a person, but do not contain all the information yet. I need to include the information in the first two columns, in which the numbers are in years, as follows:

- if the value in column 1 is smaller than a year, FirstYStage should be "Deceased", and also all the next columns (the person is still dead...); if the value is between 1 and 2, it SecondYStage should be "Deceased", and so on.
- if the value in column 2 is smaller than a year, SecondYStage should be "EndOfEvents"; if the value is between 1 and 2, it SecondYStage should be "EndOfEvents", and so on.

So the expected output in this case should be:

```
df_updated = structure(list(DeceasedDate = c(0.283219178082192, 
1.12678843226788, 
2.02865296803653, 0.892465753424658, NA, 0.88013698630137, NA
), LastClinicalEventMonthEnd = c(0.244862981988838, 1.03637744165398, 
10.9464611555048, 0.763698598427194, 3.35011412354135, 0.677397228564181, 
3.83687211440893), FirstYStage = c("Deceased", "2", "2", "Deceased", 
"2", "Deceased", "3.1"), SecondYStage = c("Deceased", "Deceased", 
"2", "Deceased", "2", "Deceased", "3.1"), ThirdYStage = c("Deceased", 
"Deceased", "Deceased", "Deceased", "2", "Deceased", "3.1"), 
FourthYStage = c("Deceased", "Deceased", "Deceased", "Deceased", 
"2", "Deceased", "3.1"), FifthYStage = c("Deceased", "Deceased", 
"Deceased", "Deceased", "LastEvent", "Deceased", "LastEvent"
)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

One important point is that "Death" should be given priority, in other words, if there is a clash and on the one hand there is a number and "death" is contradicting it, we should prefer death.

How do I do this in the most efficient way? At the moment I am doing if's but I think it is not the best course of action

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of what you are doing?

Comment: @AdamWheeler so for example, `df$FirstYStage = if_else(df$DeceasedDate <=1, "Deceased", df$FirstYStage)` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

1. Reshape from wide to long format
2. Compute years from column names
3. Selectively update the `value` column
4. Reshape back to wide format

#### data.table

As I am more fluent in `data.table` than in `dplyr` here is the approach implemented in `data.table` syntax. (Apologies but I will add a `dplyr` solution if time permits.)

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(df)[, rn := .I], measure.vars = patterns("Stage$"))
long[, year := as.integer(variable)]   # column index     
long[floor(DeceasedDate) < year, value := "Deceased"]
long[is.na(DeceasedDate) & floor(LastClinicalEventMonthEnd) + 1 < year, value := "EndOfEvents"]
dcast(long, rn + DeceasedDate + LastClinicalEventMonthEnd ~ variable)
```

> ```
>    rn DeceasedDate LastClinicalEventMonthEnd FirstYStage SecondYStage ThirdYStage FourthYStage FifthYStage
> 1:  1    0.2832192                 0.2448630    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 2:  2    1.1267884                 1.0363774           2     Deceased    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 3:  3    2.0286530                10.9464612           2            2    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 4:  4    0.8924658                 0.7636986    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 5:  5           NA                 3.3501141           2            2           2            2 EndOfEvents
> 6:  6    0.8801370                 0.6773972    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 7:  7           NA                 3.8368721         3.1          3.1         3.1          3.1 EndOfEvents
> ```

#### dplyr / tidyr

As promised, here is also a `dplyr`/`tidyr` implemention of the same approach:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key, val, ends_with("Stage"), factor_key = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(year = as.integer(key)) %>% 
  mutate(val = if_else(!is.na(DeceasedDate) & floor(DeceasedDate) < year, "Deceased", val)) %>% 
  mutate(val = if_else(is.na(DeceasedDate) & floor(LastClinicalEventMonthEnd) + 1 < year, "EndOfEvents", val)) %>% 
  select(-year) %>% 
  spread(key, val) %>% 
  arrange(rn)
```

> ```
>   DeceasedDate LastClinicalEventMonthEnd rn FirstYStage SecondYStage ThirdYStage FourthYStage FifthYStage
> 1    0.2832192                 0.2448630  1    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 2    1.1267884                 1.0363774  2           2     Deceased    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 3    2.0286530                10.9464612  3           2            2    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 4    0.8924658                 0.7636986  4    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 5           NA                 3.3501141  5           2            2           2            2 EndOfEvents
> 6    0.8801370                 0.6773972  6    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased     Deceased    Deceased
> 7           NA                 3.8368721  7         3.1          3.1         3.1          3.1 EndOfEvents
> ```

or without creating a `year` column:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(key, val, ends_with("Stage"), factor_key = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(val = if_else(!is.na(DeceasedDate) & floor(DeceasedDate) < as.integer(key), 
                       "Deceased", val)) %>% 
  mutate(val = if_else(is.na(DeceasedDate) & floor(LastClinicalEventMonthEnd) + 1 < as.integer(key), 
                       "EndOfEvents", val)) %>% 
  spread(key, val) %>% 
  arrange(rn)
```